# User notification MVVM

Tags: xaml, mvvm, notifications

I am trying to create a user notification. Ideally a toast-like notification that shows up in the corner for about three seconds.

I am using MVVM-light and I think the notification could be done using its messenger-service.

I have this class:

```
public class NotificationSync
    {
        public string Messages { get; set; }
    }
```

In one viewmodel i set up the Messenger like this:

```
 Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationSync()
    {
       Messages = "message"
    });
```

And in my MainviewModel (which is the datacontext of the view) I listen for it like this:

```
  Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationSync>(this, (action) =>
               Mess = action.Messages );
```

`Mess` is a string property on the viewmodel:

```
   private string mess;
    public string Mess
    {
        get { return mess; }
        set
        {
            mess = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Mess");
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do with mess is to bind it to my view in a toast-like manner. I.E display it for some seconds in my view. Any tips on how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a Visibility property for your toast plus a timer?

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationSync>(this, (action) =>
               Mess = action.Messages 
               ShowToast();
);

private void ShowToast()
{
    IsToastVisible = true;
    dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

void OnTimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    IsToastVisible = false;
}
```

This assumes the textbox to which Mess is bound, is also bound to IsToastVisible and it's using a VisibilityConverter.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I can absoluteley use this code but I would really like to know how i can create the toast-like piece of xaml which will show up in the corner. Thank you.

Comment: You create a Border that has a textblock inside. The Border's visibility is bound to IsToastVisible and the textblock text is bound to Mess. Here are some useful convertes http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/useful-calue-converters/